# Groupby sum in pandas and customize the df as per the conditions/requirements

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a df as shown below

```
ID      Type              Number_of_transactions     Amount
1       SuperMarket       8                          2000
2       Hospital          2                          500
1       Education         1                          1000
1       Travel            3                          600
1       Hospital          1                          800
2       Education         1                          600
1       SuperMarket       2                          100
2       SuperMarket       4                          400
3       SuperMarket       2                          300
2       Hospital          3                          200
3       Education         1                          700
3       Education         1                          100
2       Hospital          1                          1000
3       Hotel             3                          1500
3       Hotel             2                          700
4       SuperMarket       10                         900
```

From the above, I would like to prepare below dataframe.

Expected Output:

```
ID       Top1              AmountTop1        Top2          Amount_Top2
1        SuperMarket       2100              Education     1000
2        Hospital          1700              Education     600 
3        Hotel             2200              Education     800
4        SuperMarket       900               NaN           NaN
```

Explanation:

```
Top1 = Spending type where the customer spend most
AmountTop1 = Amount spend on Top1 type
Top2 = Spending type where the customer spend second largest
Amount_Top2 = Amount spend on Top2 type
```

I tried below code

```
df1 = df.groupby(['ID', 'Type']).agg({'Amount':'sum'})\
                            .rename(columns={'Amount':'Spend_By_Type'})\
                            .sort_values(by=['ID', 'Spend_By_Type'], ascending=[1, 0])\
                            .reset_index(drop=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['ID', 'Type'], as_index=False)['Amount'].sum()
df2 = (df1.loc[df1.groupby('ID')['Amount'].nlargest(2).reset_index(level=0).index]
         .rename(columns={'Type': 'Top', 'Amount': 'AmountTop'})
      )
df2['top_num'] = df2.groupby('ID').cumcount() + 1
df3 = df2.pivot(index='ID', columns='top_num').sort_index(level=[1,0],  ascending=[True, False], axis=1)
df3.columns = df3.columns.map(lambda x: ''.join(map(str, x)))
df3 = df3.reset_index()
```

Result:

```
print(df3)


   ID         Top1  AmountTop1       Top2  AmountTop2
0   1  SuperMarket      2100.0  Education      1000.0
1   2     Hospital      1700.0  Education       600.0
2   3        Hotel      2200.0  Education       800.0
3   4  SuperMarket       900.0        NaN         NaN
```

Comment: But there is another SuperMarket for ID=1 with amount 100

Comment: @Danish  Ok, probably you want to sum up them. I missed that point.  Will fix it soon!

Comment: @Danish  Edited the solution.  Please take a look!  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```py
In [104]: x = df.groupby(['ID', 'Type'], as_index=False)['Amount'].sum().sort_values(['ID', 'Amount'], ascending=[True,False]).
     ...: assign(order=lambda x: x.groupby('ID').cumcount()+1).query('order < 3').pivot_table(index='ID', columns=['order'], va
     ...: lues=['Type', 'Amount'], aggfunc='first')

In [105]: x
Out[105]:
       Amount                 Type
order       1       2            1          2
ID
1      2100.0  1000.0  SuperMarket  Education
2      1700.0   600.0     Hospital  Education
3      2200.0   800.0        Hotel  Education
4       900.0     NaN  SuperMarket        NaN
```

You can then rename the columns and re-order them as you want. This is just calculating the sums then sorting by the aggregated amount desc
We then create a column "order" that has the grouped index of the sorted df, filtering out the first two items of each group.

Answer (score 2):

Get the iniital groupby on `ID` and `Type`:

```
base_values = df.groupby(['ID', 'Type']).Amount.agg('sum')

ID  Type       
1   Education      1000
    Hospital        800
    SuperMarket    2100
    Travel          600
2   Education       600
    Hospital       1700
    SuperMarket     400
3   Education       800
    Hotel          2200
    SuperMarket     300
4   SuperMarket     900
Name: Amount, dtype: int64
```

Get the `Top1` and `Top2` via rank:

```
Top1 = (base_values[base_values.groupby("ID")
                               .rank(ascending = False)
                               .eq(1)]
          .rename_axis(['ID', 'Top1'])
          .rename('AmountTop1')
          .reset_index('Top1'))


Top2 = (base_values[base_values.groupby("ID")
                               .rank(ascending = False)
                               .eq(2)]
          .rename_axis(['ID', 'Top2'])
          .rename('AmountTop2')
          .reset_index('Top12'))
```

Combine `Top1` and `Top2` :

```
pd.concat([Top1, Top2], axis = 'columns')

           Top1  AmountTop1       Top2  AmountTop2
ID                                                
1   SuperMarket        2100  Education      1000.0
2      Hospital        1700  Education       600.0
3         Hotel        2200  Education       800.0
4   SuperMarket         900        NaN         NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

```
res = (df.groupby("ID")[["Type", "Amount"]]
         .apply(lambda s: s.groupby("Type").sum().nlargest(2, "Amount"))
         .reset_index("Type")
         .pipe(lambda df: df.set_index(df.groupby("ID").cumcount()+1, append=True))
         .unstack())

res.columns = (res.columns.map("{0[0]}{0[1]}".format)
                  .str.replace("Type", "Top")
                  .str.replace("Amount", "AmountTop"))

res = res.sort_index(axis=1, key=lambda s: s.str[-1])
```

We first group by the `ID` column and look at the 2-largest group sums over `Type`. Then we put the `Type` back into columns and append an index that would help number the values within `ID`s, and unstack it. The rest is concatenating & renaming the column names and a specific sort of them,

to get

```
>>> res

           Top1  AmountTop1       Top2  AmountTop2
ID
1   SuperMarket      2100.0  Education      1000.0
2      Hospital      1700.0  Education       600.0
3         Hotel      2200.0  Education       800.0
4   SuperMarket       900.0        NaN         NaN
```